# HTML AgilityPack Problem - Visual Basic - UTF-8

Tags: visual-studio, utf-8, html-agility-pack, basic, codepages

i tried to open a web page with HTML agility pack but always get the error:
*System.ArgumentException: """utf-8"" ist kein unterstützter Codierungsname.*

In english: "utf-8" is a not supported Codepage.

I search for tipps and hints and found some adivices to override the encoding, but result is the same error. It persists. Here is my code:

```
    Dim link As String = "https://www.wunschliste.de/suche/" & "CSI"
    Dim doc = New HtmlWeb
    doc.OverrideEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8")
    Dim HtmlDoc As HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument
    HtmlDoc = doc.Load(link)
```

I also copied an example in c# to a new project and the result is the same...

```
var htmlWeb = new HtmlWeb(); 
htmlWeb.OverrideEncoding = Encoding.UTF8; 
var doc = htmlWeb.Load("https://www.wunschliste.de/suche/" & "CSI");
```

What can I do?

The website is coded as:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: Can you check the value of the C# constant to see that it is exactly what you think it is?  It's possible, however remote, that "utf-8" is not the exact value of that constant in C# and whatever else it might be might make it work in VB.

Answer (score 0):

The issue can be closed. The agility pack got an update at the weekend and this fixed the problem!
Thanks a lot!